# Running multiple instances of a program to speed up process?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a program that performs a long running process. Loops through thousands of records, one at a time, and calls a stored proc each iteration. Would running two instances of a program like this with one processing half the records and the other processing the other half speed up the processing?

Here are the scenarios:

1. 1 program, running long running process
2. 2 instances of program on same server, connecting to same database, each responsible for processing half (50%) of the records.
3. 2 instance on different server, connecting to the same database, each responsible for half (50%) of the records.

Would scenario 2 or 3 run twice as fast as 1? Would there be a difference between 2 and 3? The main bottleneck is the stored proc call that takes around half a second.

Thanks!

Comment: depends entirely on your setup. a single-core/single-thread db server won't benefit from multiple parallel clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends what the stored procedure is doing.  If the stored procedure is going to be updating the records, and you have a single database instance then there is going to be contention when writing the data back.

The values at play here, are:

1. The time it takes to read the data in to your application memory (and this is also dependent on whether you are using client-side or sql-server-side cursors).
2. The time it takes to process, or do your application logic.
3. The time it takes to write an updated item back (assuming the proc updates).

One solution (and this is by no means a perfect solution without knowing the exact requirements), is:

1. Have X servers read Y records, and process them.
2. Have those servers write the results back to a dedicated writing server in a serialized fashion to avoid the contention.

Comment: The application logic doesn't take long, it's the third-party stored proc that is called in an loop on the application side (10,000 + times) and taking 0.5 seconds to complete the call each time. Instead of x servers, could I use 1 server and multiple instances of the same program to split up record processing, or are multiple servers required for that? I'm not sure what is meant by writing the results in a serialized fashion. I just pass parameters to a stored proc and it fires off.

Comment: @chobo, honestly it all depends on reads, what is happening in the processing and how many writes are going on.  If there's a gazillion writes spread across X servers, then your DB server is going to be bottle-necked unless you set up some sort of replication strategy.  This is very implementation-dependant, hence my answer is one work-around but might not fit your needs whatsoever.  The actual problem you're trying to solve and what it is doing, is what we need to know to help :)

Comment: Thanks Moo. Um, all I can say is the stored proc is transactional, and performs a lot of integrity checks and writes, it's for an inventory management system. I don't know how mssql 2008 would handle multiple calls to that proc at close to or at the same time. If you need some specific information or an area I should be looking into let me know :) Thanks!

Comment: @chobo, so if the stored proc does the heavy-lifting, what are the application servers doing?

Comment: Not much, they are just vm's. One VM is just dedicated to running this.

Comment: @chobo - I guess I am asking why the application *exists* if the database procs are doing the heavy lifting...

Comment: It exists because the application has to retrieve, parse, and gather information from a lot of different databases / tables. Placing all that logic in a stored proc would be a nightmare to maintain, or even create

Comment: @chobo, then my solution isn't too shabby.  Have the servers do the bulk work of gathering and pass them to a 3rd server (web API?  JSON?  ServiceStack?  Your choice), and have that web-service batch things up and perform the rights independently of the processing.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to batch stored proc calls

Comment: @chobo, well you don't have to batch them.  Just offload them to something else to serialize the calls rather than contending.  If the procs are, as you say, doing a lot of transactional work - it be best they *never* contend and that suggests serializing them in some fashion.  That can be as simple as a webservice that takes an id (for example) and adds it to a queue.

Comment: Could you give a simple example of serialization of a stored proc? I don't quite understand how that all works.

Comment: @chobo, well the idea is - is that once you've done processing the data, you "post" it to another server (via a webservice) and it serializes the writes.  When I say that, I mean that because your other servers process and all post to the 3rd server, the 3rd server can simply called this stored proc on each request and there is no contention as it is queued.

Comment: Forgive me slowness but I don't quite grasp how offloading the data to another server for the stored proc and then calling it there would make any difference? About 95% of the running time is just the stored proc running. I was wondering if I could somehow run multiple programs or processes and have it speed up that process just by being able to call the proc twice as many times in the same time.

Comment: @chobo, and therein lies the rub.  It was not apparent from your question.  My solution still works, but again.. if 95% of the time is in the stored-proc then the processing servers cease to be relevant.  You could look in to replicated databases that allow updates and have several *writing* servers with one processing one... again, the bottlenecks are everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for you help and patience! I'll look into database replication, since the database seems to be the bottleneck

Answer (score 4):

This depends on a lot of factors. Also note that threads may be more appropriate than processes. Or maybe not. Again: it depends. But: is this work CPU-bound? Network-bound? Or bound by what the database server can do? Adding concurrency helps with CPU-bound, and when talking to multiple independent resources. Fighting over the same network connection or the same database server is unlikely to improve things - and can make things much worse.

Frankly, from the sound of it your best bet may be to re-work the sproc to work in batches (rather than individual records).

To answer this question properly you need to know what the resource utilization of the database server currently us: can it take extra load? Or simpler - *just try it and see*.

Comment: I don't think the process is CPU-bound, it just takes awhile to loop through 10000+ records and having the stored proc take 0.5 seconds to complete for each one. I'm not sure if that is database bound or network bound. The stored proc is part of a third-party erp system and modifying it would be a last resort.

Comment: @chobo well, what is the server CPU/disk/etc looking like currently: does it look like it is idling?

Comment: I'd have to check the disk and network, but the CPU and memory usage on the server running the program are quite low and steady

Comment: I think the actual use-case scenario really needs to be put in the question here.  Without real record-numbers and knowing what the processing *is* and what that proc *does*, we may as well hold our fingers in the air :)

Comment: @Moo indeed - hence my "just try it". Of course, the next concern then becomes: *is it concurrency-safe*?

Comment: The program that runs this process is set to run early in the morning, triggered by windows task scheduler. It adjusts inventory levels between a pos system and an erp system. Not sure if that helps, but it just gives you the overview of what is going on

Comment: @chobo not really, no

Comment: lol, no worries. If there is some specific information that would be beneficial let me know. Thanks